# how to get the text content of an element with no ID in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get a particular text content of the heading element which does not have any ID associated with it. What javascript code should I use to get the content 'I only want this one'.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.one span');
console.log(elements[0].text);
```

This code is not giving the desired output

```
<h5 class="one two three four">
<span class="s1 s2">I don't want this</span>
I only want this one</h5>
```

I expect the output to be 'I only want this one', but I am getting undefined...

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to select the *text node*, which is not an element, so you can't select it immediately with `querySelectorAll` (or `querySelector`) - so, first select the parent (the `.one`), then navigate to its last child:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.one');
const textNode = parent.lastChild;
console.log(textNode.textContent);
```

```html
<h5 class="one two three four">
  <span class="s1 s2">I don't want this</span>
I only want this one</h5>
```

Note that if you just want the first element which matches a particular selector string, it's more appropriate to use `querySelector` (which returns that element), rather than `querySelectorAll` (which returns a collection, from which you must proceed to select the first element in it).

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)